# LeetCode problem (longest substring) Python

Tags: python, substring

I am trying to solve this problem where I have to find the longest substring. I tested my function, and it seems to work out fine. EXCEPT, when I submit the work, there is a runtime error because of b=s[0]? What am I missing?

```
class Solution(object):
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
    b=s[0]
    h=[]
    N=len(s)
    for i in range (N):
        if i<N-1 and (s[i+1] not in b):
            b+=s[i+1]
            h.append(b)
        else:
            b=s[i]     
    max=0
    for j in range(len(h)):
        if max<len(h[j]):
            max=len(h[j])
    if max==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return max
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: int
    """
```

Comment: Consider the edge case of the empty string `""`: `""[0]` will trigger "string index out of range".

Comment: Don't use `max` as a variable name, is a builtin function